# What should I choose for an icon for "praise"?

Tags: icon, symbolism

I want to make an icon that symbolises action such as praise. Thumbs up icon for "Like" is great. But it's just a casual thing to do. I want something that we do for something like

1. Show appreciation
2. Show respect for someone's achievement
3. Show gratitude

For example something that would express my emotions to someone who has either done something amazing or someone who has helped me tremendously. (Like the person who answers this question).

**What i've thought so far**
Someone already mentioned it in an answer, I thought of something like a heart with a hand below it. As the hand is giving a lift to the heart. But i have to put a favourite icon with it which is obviously a heart icon.
I'm just confused. I think a hand and a heart should do, What do you guys think. It won't confuse with favourite icon rite?

Comment: Hi Mukul, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: My first thought was a gold star. But better yet is a "blue ribbon." I don't know to describe one. A many pointed star or circle with two ribbons coming out of the bottom.

Comment: You can use stars for favorite as well, instead of heart. I wouldn't say "obviously a heart icon represents favorite".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can combine a heart and hand emoji to create a new symbol for love and appreciation. Like a hand cradling a heart :)

Comment: You can have the hand underneath the heart as if it were levitating just a bit and have 3 strokes above the heart going outward like it's shining.

Comment: How about a heart with wings rather?

Answer (score 1):

Two hands up going away from one another

Comment: I dont know why this got downvoted. Just becajsd Queeki doesnt embed an image doesnt mean that his pretty good description on how he imagines a visual clue for "praise" are less values than the others

Answer (score 1):

Blue Ribbon

[image]

filling up characters so I can post

Answer (score 0):

The most common icon for this type of feedback is a **thumbs up** icon. You are correct though. It is generally a more casual thing.

If you want to elude to more of an "achievement" then something along the lines of a **state fair ribbon** or **star** may be more appropriate.

The [**Noun project**](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=achievement) has a ton of icons for "achievement".

Answer (score 0):

Despite the risk of religious iconography not being terribly cross-cultural, I'm leaning towards a stick figure person with a halo. Selection results in a bigger and brighter halo.

Answer (score 0):

A trophy perhaps? If that's not what you're looking for, what about a certificate or medal?

[image: Suggestion]

If none of these, there's also a checkmark.